# Injecting ViewModels with an Activity context dependency

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm using dagger.android and want to inject ViewModels. On the other hand, I have an `ApiModule` that depends on activity context,

Here is the `AppComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        ViewModelModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApp> {}
}
```

The `ViewModelModule` provides ViewModelProvider.Factory

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(MyAppViewModelFactory factory);
}
```

Here is the `ActivityBindingModule`:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    //MainActivity
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {
            MainActivityModule.class,
            ApiModule.class
    })
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivityInjector();

    @Module
    abstract class MainActivityModule {
        @ActivityScoped
        @Binds
        abstract Activity bindMainActivity(MainActivity activity);

        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ViewModelKey(UserViewModel.class)
        abstract ViewModel bindUserViewModel(UserViewModel userViewModel);
    }

    //SecondActivity
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {
            SecondActivityModule.class,
            ApiModule.class
    })
    abstract SecondActivity contributeSecondActivityInjector();

    @Module
    abstract class SecondActivityModule {
        @ActivityScoped
        @Binds
        abstract Activity bindSecondActivity(SecondActivity activity);

        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ViewModelKey(DetailViewModel.class)
        abstract ViewModel bindDetailViewModel(DetailViewModel detailViewModel);
    }
}
```

I have these injection hierarchies:

- `MainActivity --inject--> ViewModelProvider.Factory --inject--> MyAppViewModelFactory --inject--> UserViewModel --inject--> UserRepository --inject--> ApiService --inject--> Activity context`
- `SecondActivity --inject--> ViewModelProvider.Factory --inject--> MyAppViewModelFactory --inject--> DetailViewModel --inject--> DetailRepository --inject--> ApiService --inject--> Activity context`

We provide:

- `Activity` context on `MainActivityModule` (and `SecondActivityModule`)
- `ApiService` on `ApiModule` (added to modules of each activity on `ActivityBindingModule`)
- `UserRepository` and `DetailRepository` are `@Singleton`
- `UserViewModel` on `MainActivityModule` and `DetailViewModel` on `SecondActivityModule`
- `MyAppViewModelFactory` is @Singleton

Here is `MyAppViewModelFactory`:

```
@Singleton
public class MyAppViewModelFactoryimplements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

    @Inject
    MyAppViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
        this.creators = creators;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @NonNull
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
        if (creator == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                    creator = entry.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
        }
        try {
            return (T) creator.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
com.example.viewmodels.MyAppViewModelFactory.<init>(creators)
com.example.viewmodels.MyAppViewModelFactory is injected at
com.example.di.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
com.example.activities.MainActivity.viewModelFactory
com.example.activities.MainActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
component path: com.example.di.AppComponent ? com.example.di.ActivityBindingModule_ContributeMainActivityInjector.MainActivitySubcomponent
```

I tried to move `bindUserViewModel` (from `MainActivityModule`) and `bindDetailViewModel` (from `SecondActivityModule`) to `ViewModelModule` and I got this error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] tk.medlynk.medlynk.http.ApiService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
com.example.http.ApiService is injected at
com.example.repositories.UserRepository.<init>(apiService)
com.example.repositories.UserRepository is injected at
com.example.viewmodels.UserViewModel.<init>(userRepo)
com.example.viewmodels.UserViewModel is injected at
com.example.di.ViewModelModule.bindUserViewModel(userViewModel)
java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
com.example.viewmodels.MyAppViewModelFactory.<init>(creators)
com.example.viewmodels.MyAppViewModelFactory is injected at
com.example.di.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
com.example.activities.MainActivity.viewModelFactory
com.example.activities.MainActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
component path: com.example.di.AppComponent ? com.example.di.ActivityBindingModule_ContributeMainActivityInjector.MainActivitySubcomponent
```

What am I missing here? the [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/di/ActivityBindingModule.kt) project does the same thing without problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to restructure your Dagger2 setup in the Application and Activity levels.
Secondly, your `ViewModelProviderFactory` class is somewhat complicated. I will restructure your code for you now.

**Application Level**

`AppComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
    AppModule.class,
    ActivityBindingModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApp> {
@Component.Builder
abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApp> {}
}
```

`ActivityBindingModule`

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
  abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();

  //This goes for other activities
}
```

`AppModule` This class provides only classes that are common and may be used in 
 any activity throughout the application.

```
@Module
class AppModule {

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  //Your ApiService interface comes here
  //Retrofit
  //Database
}
```

`App` class should extend DaggerApplication for simplicity. This automatically injects its members

```
  class MyApp extends DaggerApplication

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
      }

      @Override
      protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> 
      applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerHorizonMainComponent.builder().create(this);
   }
```

**Activity Level**

`MainActivityModule` This is where you have your `ViewModel` and `ViewModelProviderFactory`

```
@Module
class MainACtivityModule {

@Provides
MainActivityViewModel provideMainActivityViewModel(){
    return new MainActivityViewModel();
}

@Provides
ViewModelProvider.Factory provideViewModelProvider(MainActivityViewModel 
viewModel){
    return new ViewModelProviderFactory<>(viewModel);
}

//Your repository comes here too
}
```

`ViewModel` class

```
 class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

 @Inject
 public MyViewModel(){
 }
 }
```

`ViewModelProviderFactory` Just copy this code

```
 public class ViewModelProviderFactory<V> implements 
      ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        private V viewModel;

        public ViewModelProviderFactory(V viewModel) {
           this.viewModel = viewModel;
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(viewModel.getClass())) {
                 return (T) viewModel;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class name");
        }
    }
```

Finally, in your `MainActivity` class, you inject the ViewModelProviderFactory. You don't need to inject Dagger here since you are extending it to DaggerAppCompatActivity

```
   public class Mainactivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity{

       @Inject
       ViewModelProvider.Factory factory;
       private MyViewModel viewModel;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //You set your view here
       viewmodel = 
       ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(MyViewModel.class);

       }
     }
```

Comment: Tnx, but I used `ViewModelProviderFactory` as same as google sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/b1a194c1ae267258cd002e2e1c102df7180be473/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.java and same as https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/shared/di/IOSchedViewModelFactory.kt

Comment: Let me know if there is any issue regarding the above codes or if you have any question. Hope this solves the issues you have

Answer (score 0):

All your setting sounds correct. **The main cause is `ApiService` is not provided.**

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]
>   [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
>   tk.medlynk.medlynk.http.ApiService cannot be provided without an
>   @Provides-annotated method.

To resolve it you just provide it in some module.

```
class AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApiService(): ApiService {
        ....
    }
}
```